# Firefox white box while playing embedded WMV file

Tags: asp.net, firefox, embed, windows-media-player

WMV files are not playing in mozilla browser **(version : 17.0.1)** for the first time while loading browser, instead it show a white box. When I switch between tabs or open applications and come back, it works (video starts playing). I have googled a lot regarding this issue but could not find any solution.

I have no idea as what is preventing me from doing this either a browser setting or code problem.

There is no problem while playing the same file in other browsers.

Please help me in this regard.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Me also facing same issue. If making tab to any element and click the object tag its get active(showing video).

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution for this.
On create the object tag in first child of the body and re-attach the object tag to our required div using javascript/jQuery. Refer the [sample](http://jsbin.com/oqehuc/9) and [code](http://jsbin.com/oqehuc/9/edit).